# Adding filter criteria under Views-Frontpage

Tags: views

Im watching youtube video #40 in the Drupal 8 Site Building Course.
Instructor is adding a Filter Criteria under Views, then Frontpage. So we click on ADD, then he wants us to search for "Node" and select "Type".
But we can't find "Type" when doing this?
 We are on the version 8.7.1.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the "node" part. Simply search for "type". I'm guessing you want the "Content type" entry under the "Content" Category. You can scroll down without searching to locate it in the list. Searching only makes it quicker, it doesn't add new entries based on your input.

Comment: You are told to search for Node to shorten list, but yes I'm trying to find "Type".  And "Type" is not anywhere on this list to select.  I'm trying to use a view on Frontpage that is NOT of Type "Basic Page".   But since Node....Type is not found is the filter list I'm unable to?

Comment: I found out the answer. The filter is now called "Content Type" with new version of Drupal.